# Vorgeschoben (in context)

Tags: meaning-in-context

Als ich [diesen Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Grappa) kurz überflog, fand ich diesen Satz:

> Er [ein Berg] liegt als **vorgeschobenes** Gebirgsmassiv zwischen den Flüssen Brenta und Piave.

Mein Problem ist „vorgeschobenes“. Ich habe in verschiedenen Wörterbüchern nachgeschlagen (Duden auch), aber ich fand keine Erklärung, die passend scheint. Könnten Sie mir bitte die Bedeutung des Wortes in diesem Kontext erklären?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you the [DWDS-Entry for "vorschieben](http://dwds.de/?qu=vorschieben), you'll find three possible meanings the second of which is relevant here:

> *etw., jmdn. nach vorn schieben*: den Unterkiefer, Mund, das Kinn, die Unterlippe vorschieben

`vorgeschoben` is the past participle of `vorschieben`, so the phrase `vorgeschobenes Gebirgsmassiv` means, that this mountain range lies like having been pushed to front. (Possibly, this was indeed true when tectonic forces pushed it to the front millions of years ago. But this need not be the case.)

Comment: Thanks! It definitely sounds reasonable to me, although I'm no geography expert.